# How can I change the default error handler in Dingo/Api?

Tags: laravel, dingo-api

I am building a REST API using Laravel framework and the Dingo API library. Everything works well except that I don't know how I can customize the default error handler when exception happens.

For example, when my code run error, the response is simply this:

```
{
     "message": "Error",
     "status_code": 500
}
```

How can I change this response to my own format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- edit the errorFormat in config/api.php as you want.

```
    'errorFormat' => [
        'message' => ':message',
        'errors' => ':errors',
        'code' => 0,
        'status_code' => ':status_code',
        'result' => ':errors',
        'debug' => ':debug',
    ],
```

- you could also try process the exception like 
  https://github.com/dingo/api/pull/797#issuecomment-194186577